# Is it all right to write a memoir like a novel?

Tags: fiction, characters, novel, memoir

I wanted to share my true story as if I were writing a fictional story. For example, the author Terry McMillan's novel called, "Disappearing Acts", wrote a fictional story shared with her many readers while I am sharing my story as if it were a fictional story. Because my story is true, I made sure that all names were changed. I chose to share my story as a fictional story because my readers connect better with my story being written as if my story was actually fictional. For example, my readers connecting with a fictional book with fictional characters like Mary Monroe's "God Don't Like Ugly." I chose to use my true story about the abuse that I had endured at an early age, both physical and sexual adolescent abuse, to connect and help other victims better.

Comment: FWIW, I've never heard of either of these authors you reference. But if your readers like it, it sounds like it was a good decision.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Writing S.E! Take a [tour](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tour), and visit our [help center](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help)!

Comment: @Alexandrang They've already taken the tour, they have the badge for doing so, but I appreciate your enthusiasm.

Answer (score 1):

What you are writing is described as an [autobiographical novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autobiographical_novel).  There have been many, so they are indeed all right.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! Many authors have already done it before. I think that writing your memoir as a novel makes it more engaging. Many authors have already done it before, such as the book ["Educated](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0399590501) by Tara Westover.